# Windows server 2012 sign in issue

Tags: windows-server-2012

Before installing active directory services and joining a local domain, i created 3 local users for my brothers but after joining the domain i only can see my user(administrator) and a user called other user which provide a way to sign in the local users but i cannot sign in. Can anybody tell me the correct way to sign in the other local users or tell me the way that how can i show the other local user on the log on screen.

Comment: 1) Off topic on this site.  2) Please do not [post on multiple SE sites](http://superuser.com/questions/620396/windows-server-2012-sign-in-issue)

Comment: isn't it server related?

Comment: [SF] explicitly excludes home usage. While you did not say 'at home' the 'i created 3 local users for my brothers` really points to a home setup.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly you wish to log in locally on a server running AD DS? If that is true, then it is not possible. You can only log in locally on other computers, which are not DCs or log in using domain users on a DC.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: yes its a AD DS. then there is no way my brothers can use the computer?

Comment: You can always create domain users in Active Directory

Comment: i promoted the users to server operators and it solved the problem.